# Showing a group is abelian of order $\det(M)$

Tags: matrices, abelian-groups

I'm having some difficulty with this question, I don't really know how to tackle it, if anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Let $M \in \Bbb Z^{n \times n} $ be of matrix-rank n with rows $\underline m_1,\underline m_2,\cdots,\underline m_n$. Let $S:=\langle \underline m_1,\underline m_2,\cdots,\underline m_n\rangle \le \Bbb Z^n$ and $A:=\Bbb Z^n/S$. Show that A is a finite abelian group of order $\det(M)$.

Comment: In order for the statement to be meaningful, it should be $\lvert\det(M)\rvert$: exchanging two columns would not change the subgroup $S$, but would change the sign of the determinant.

Comment: i think you are in my class, MA605?
message me rt326@kent.ac.uk
we can work on this assessment together

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for the first part**:

It is a finitely generated abelian group, and tensoring with $\mathbf Q$ above $\mathbf Z$, you obtain
$$S\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q\simeq \mathbf Z^n\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q\simeq \mathbf Q^n,$$
hence $\;A\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q=\{0\}$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this does not help tell you that the finite group has order $\mathrm{det}(M)$

Comment: It shows it's a finitely generated torsion group. For the determinant, you have the *Invariant factors theorem* as a tool.

Comment: Thank you. It might be useful to OP (especially if unfamiliar with tensoring,) that this only helps with the first part.

Comment: @AndresMejia: You're probably right. I've added this information. As to the  tensor product with $\mathbf Q$, the O.P. may also think intyerms of  rings or modules of fractions.